# Simple conversion of BAT file to .sh file

Tags: batch-file, sh

I am very unfamiliar with writing or converting a BAT file into `.sh` file.

I really need to convert this `.bat` file into `.sh` file.  If someone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.

```
@echo off
java -cp SqlLite.jar;oracle.jar;mysql.jar;mail.jar;activation.jar -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel -Xms32m -Xmx512m SqlLite
```

Comment: As a side note, you can't really convert from batch scripts to shell or bash scripts, as you can't really convert from say Java to C# ; what you can do is re-implement the algorithm your script implements in another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(UPDATE: note Klitos's answer, which shows that on unix systems, java expects `:` instead of `;` in classpath argument.  Original answer follows.)

In .sh, you don't need `@echo off`, and any argument which contains `;`
will have to be in quotes because `;` terminates a command line in .sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp "SqlLite.jar;oracle.jar;mysql.jar;mail.jar;activation.jar" -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel -Xms32m -Xmx512m SqlLite
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to run your sh script on a Unix-like system such as OSX or Linux, then the java -cp (classpath) option separates elements with a colon instead of a semicolon:

```
java -cp SqlLite.jar:oracle.jar:mysql.jar:mail.jar:activation.jar -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel -Xms32m -Xmx512m SqlLite
```

Also, you might want to change the default look and feel from Windows to something else.

Comment: I like your preface, but I think it could be more specific : if the `java` executable is the linux version, `:` should be used, regardless of the OS, as opposed to `;` for window's `java`. For example, a shell script being executed in cygwin (or Window10's bash shell ?)  should still use `;` since it will call window's `java`

Comment: @Aaron yes, indeed. In fact, to be more precise, Java uses the `path.separator` system property, which is by default ";" in the Windows version of Java and ":" in other versions. You could override it by saying "java -Dpath.separator=; ..." but that would be pointless as you could just as easily use the system-default path separator in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is change the file extension. Change the .bat ending to a .sh ending. If you are using windows 10 and the file extension does not appear when you are browsing go to "View" and tick the box on the right that says file extensions.

To do this with in cmd (or on a batch file) type

```
rename c:\my\first\file\name.bat c:\my\second\file\name.sh
```

The `rename` can be replaced with `ren`, and if any directories (folders) or files have spaces in them (c:\users\%username%\desktop\this is my file.bat), put them in "quotes" ("c:\users\%username%\desktop\this is my file.bat").

Good luck on whatever you are doing.